# Default to HTTPS for Rails5.0 App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, https, routes

I have a basic rails app running in AWS EB, and have made available the SSL layer using the Amazon Certificate Manager. How do you reroute "example.com" to "https://www.example.com" automatically? This is so the app runs the SSL certificate for the app visits.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below line to `config/environments/production.rb` file:

```
config.force_ssl = true # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Puneet18

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add HTTPS redirect config to your source code of the rails app. There is a way to make advanced settings in elastic beanstalk, using conf files in a folder named .ebextensions

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html

Specifically you will need to create a conf file with the below content and add it to your .ebextensions folder.

```
Files:
"/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl_rewrite.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
        RewriteEngine On
        <If "-n '%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}' && %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} != 'https'">
        RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
        </If>
```

Please see this AWS forum link for more details. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=739990